# React login with JWT Authentication WP plugin

Tags: reactjs, wordpress

I have used JWT to login from my app via WordPress rest API, I have configured all things. When I have entered the username and password correctly I get success and everything is ok but when I empty one of them I see blew error in my console, I want to remove it.

POST http://localhost/test/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token 403 (Forbidden)

[image: Console error]

What is the problem? This is my code I have used to connect API:

```
  axios.post(`http://localhost/test/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token`, {
    username: '',
    password: ''
  })
    .then(res => {
      console.log('result');
      console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('error');
      console.log(err.response);
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you don't have clear how the token flow works.

The endpoint `/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token` validate the username and the password, if both are correct the endpoint returns a JWT Token

```
{
    "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC9qd3QuZGV2IiwiaWF0IjoxNDM4NTcxMDUwLCJuYmYiOjE0Mzg1NzEwNTAsImV4cCI6MTQzOTE3NTg1MCwiZGF0YSI6eyJ1c2VyIjp7ImlkIjoiMSJ9fX0.YNe6AyWW4B7ZwfFE5wJ0O6qQ8QFcYizimDmBy6hCH_8",
    "user_display_name": "admin",
    "user_email": "admin@localhost.dev",
    "user_nicename": "admin"
}
```

this token should stored on your app and then added as the authentication method for all the subsequent calls to your API.

If the username or password is missing in the `/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token` request you should expect the error you are seeing right now.

Comment: Actually I get this error im my chrome console but in firefox isn't.

Comment: Hi Enrique! Could you please see my question at https://stackoverflow.com/q/74111675