# WordPress: Can't access REST API /posts endpoint with JWT Auth plugin

Tags: wordpress, jwt, wordpress-rest-api

When I send credentials to the JWT Auth plugin endpoint, I successfully receive the response like

```
{"token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJp...","user_email":"my-email@example.com","user_nicename":"admin","user_display_name":"admin"}
```

And when I send the token to the `/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token/validate` endpoint, I receive `status":200`, so the token is ok.

But when I try to access the `/posts/1` (or `/posts`) WP REST API endpoint sending client JS request with the token like

```
let token = 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJp...'; // all three components

fetch('http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/1', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token
    }
})
.then(response => response.text())
.then(text => {
    console.log(text);
});
```

I receive the error

> {"code":"rest_cannot_edit","message":"Sorry, you are not allowed to
> edit this post.","data":{"status":401}}

What's wrong?

---

**EDIT**

I receive the same error when disable the JWT Auth plugin. This means two things: 1) POST requests to core REST API are disallowed by default and 2) the plugin doesn't intercept calls to REST API.

Comment: Tbh I don't see the point in JWT... In any case I would say that because JWT is implementing another type of login to WordPress, both type of login might not communicate together, and if you restricted your REST access through `is_user_logged_in` then I would guess that `is_user_logged_in` doesn't considered you logged-in.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, I guess it has something to do with the latest 6.1 Wordpress update. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @stckvrw Ok, thank you :) I'll dig a bit in the problem the next days, I'll let you know if I find a solution

Comment: @stckvrw I've got it working again, I was using [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/), I've replaced it with [this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-auth/), did not have to edit anything and it worked fine again. Only difference I've found (for now) is that the token is returned inside `response.data.token` while before it was just `response.token`